# bringToFront() method equivalent in OpenLayers

Tags: leaflet, openlayers, layers

Does OpenLayers have a method similar to `bringToFront` in Leaflet?
In Leaflet this works as follows. If I have a layer called geometry this method will bring that layer to the top of the other layers so it won't be covered.
An exampe in Leaflet is:

```
var geometry=L.geoJSON(geojson).addTo(map);
geometry.bringToFront();
```

I would like to do something like this in OpenLayers.

Comment: Please edit your question and add relevant OpenLayers code where you would like to put layer/feature to the front.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the docs](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_layer_Tile-TileLayer.html#setZIndex), you can set the Z Index of layers. Hopefully this does what you need. Keep safe...